# iOS: Body fixed, div scroll. How?

Tags: html, ios, css

For full compatibility, and just as a 'hack' for **older** iOS devices (on which it's difficult to add a fixed top bar or fixed menu), I fixed the position of my page body (to prevent elements from scrolling), that seems to be a solution to make the several page element fix on screen on those devices.

I made a div that should be scrollable.
Only that div I want to be able to scroll, also on the older iOS devices. But it doesn't work. When I try to scroll, the body tries to scroll (which is fixed) instead of the scrollable element.

I made an example that is supposed to be able to scroll down to number 23.
But on an older iOS it still doesn't scroll at all. I did several things that makes it more likely that it should scroll, but it doesn't on older iOS devices.

What do I wrong?

```
body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
}

.contentwrap {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  position: static;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}


<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#page 1">Section 1</a>
<span><a href="#page 2">Section 1A</a></span>
<span><a href="#page 3">Section 1B</a></span>
<span><a href="#page 4">Section 1C</a></span>
</li>
<li><a href="#page 5">Section 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="contentwrap">1 <br> 2 <br> 3 <br> 4 <br> 5 <br> 6 <br> 7 etc...</div>
```

Complete codes to number 23:

https://jsfiddle.net/vf18x37n/

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the part that allows it to scroll !important.  That way it overrides
what ever is causing it not to scroll.

EXAMPLE:

```
#scroll {
    overflow-y:scroll !important;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you sydluce. Good tip, but doesn't work for some reason. When I try to scroll, the body tries to scroll (which is fixed) instead of the scrollable element. Anybody experience with this?

Comment: I have no experience with that sadly. :/